# Python: Looping Through Rows in a Dict/Dataframe to Make a CSV and send it to its appropriate Recipient as an Email

Tags: python, database, loops, email

I have a question regarding a loop that would email a separate file (from the same file location) to a separate recipient until the list of rows in the dataframe or dictionary is exhausted. I basically have a hadoop connection using impyla in which I use a raw input to manually look up data via SQL and send an email out to a recipient; however, I would like to automate this further by creating a loop statement that looks through a reference dataframe/dictionary (depending on which is more efficient) to save a unique file per row and send out the email to the recipient within the same row until the loop finishes. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated! I have done simple loops, but for some reason, I cannot think of the most optimal way of doing this. My current code is below with the types of variables I would like to set up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from impala.dbapi import connect
#Imports required libraries for dataframe manipulation, connection to hadoop
conn = connect(host="hostname", port=10000)
#establishes a connection to host hadoop server

ID = raw_input("Please enter the ID")
path = "C:\users\myself\desktop/The_%s_Report.csv" %lookup
#sets the save path for the new file and will serve as the attachment path for the email

#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = "ID", "lookup", "recipient")
#dict = {"ID", "lookup", "recipient"}
sql = "SELECT * FROM %s" %ID
#SQL expression that needs to be edited before going into cursor.execute() command
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
#fetches the table outlined by the sql variable.

df = pd.DataFrame(data = results, columns = ["Column1", "Column2", 
"Column3", "Column4", "Column5"])
#Establishes dataframe from the hadoop fetch resutls

df.to_csv(path, sep=",", index_label= None, index = False)
#Pushes the file out to a specified filepath
cursor.close()


import win32com.client

olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Sample Report %s" %lookup
#need to create a variable with lookup row value in the dataframe
newMail.Body = "Filler text"
newMail.To = "%s" recipient
attachment1 = path
newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
newMail.Send()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a simple list of dictionaries as you specified:

```
recipients = [
     {"id": "ID1", "lookup": "lookup1", "recipient": "recipient1"},
     {"id": "ID2", "lookup": "lookup2", "recipient": "recipient2"},
     {"id": "ID3", "lookup": "lookup3", "recipient": "recipient3"}
]
```

Reformat your script with some functions like `get_data`, `create_csv` and `send_email`

And then iterate them with a for loop:

```
for recipient in recipients:
    data = get_data(recipient["id"])
    csv_file = create_csv(recipient["lookup"], data)
    send_email(csv_file, recipient["lookup"], recipient["recipient"])
```

Also, If possible, try to minimize the SQL queries and do the manipulation in pandas.

EDIT: Modified version of https://pastebin.com/6ZGJMGGS:

```
reference = [
    {'id': '4', "lookup": "'Name1", "recipient": "me.com"},
    {'id': '56', "lookup": "Name2", "recipient": "you.com"},
    {'id': '76', "lookup": "Name3", "recipient": "them.com"}
]


def get_data(ID):
    sql = " SELECT %s from Main" %ID
    #SQL expression that needs to be edited before going into cursor.execute() command
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results

    #Enters the path of the save file and appends the DSP ID to the title

def create_csv(company, table):
    path = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop/The_%s_Report.csv" %company

    df = pd.DataFrame(data = table, columns = ["Date", "Thangs", "Stuff", "$$$", "Employees"])
    #Creates Data Frame for the results variable
    df = df[["Date", "Stuff", "Thangs", "$$$", "Employees"]]
    #Re-orders the columns for easy readability
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
    df.sort_values(by = 'Date', axis=0, ascending = 'True', inplace=True)
    #Converts the date to datetime variable and reorders the dates
    df["Thangs"] = df["Thangs"].astype('float')
    df["$$$"] = df["$$$"].astype('int')
    df.to_csv(path, sep=",", index_label= None, index = False)
    return path

def send_email(csv_file, company, recipient):
    olMailItem = 0x0
    obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    newMail.Subject = "Sample Report - Live Test Run %s" %company
    newMail.Body = "Text Text Text"
    newMail.To = recipient
    #newMail.CC = ""
    #newMail.BCC = "address"
    attachment1 = csv_file
    newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
    #newMail.display()
    newMail.Send()

for recipient in reference:
    table = get_data(recipient[['id']], recipient['lookup'])
    csv_file = create_csv(recipient['lookup'], table)
    send_email(csv_file, recipient['lookup'], recipient['recipient'])
```

Comment: I will give this a try! Thank you for your input!

Comment: I have been having trouble iterating over the list because I get the error: 
     'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Here's my pastebin file link to the code: https://pastebin.com/6ZGJMGGS

Comment: @Korean_Yeezus You need to return values in your functions

Comment: Thanks @fedterzi,

However, I think the for loop doesn't like the string value from the dictionary.  It keeps asking for an int values (what I assume to be an list index?)

Comment: @Korean_Yeezus Using string values as keys for dictionaries is completely fine, if your id needs to be an int, you can remove quotes from the dictionary like `{'id': 4, "lookup": "'Name1", "recipient": "me.com"},`

Comment: It worked! I basically turned the list of dicts to a dataframe and was able to retain the string value formatting of all values. Thank you for the support!